# How to execute an error free transaction when querying through link server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a vb.net application that execute more than 3 queries at the same time. Specialy the `INSERT` query.

**Code:**

```
Sub PerformSave()
  Using cmd as new SqlCommand(query1,conn)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using

  Using cmd as new SqlCommand(query2,conn)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using

  Using cmd as new SqlCommand(query3,conn)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
End Sub
```

What bothers me most is, I notice that after the 1st query has successully executed the internet connection was lost and the rest of the transactions failed. All I want is if the 1st query failed the rest should be failed as well, the reason is this all of the data are connected to each other but stored into different tables.

Comment: [SqlConnection.BeginTransaction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=netframework-4.8) or [TransactionScope Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Where did conn come from? I guess it must be an open connection. I don't think it is a good idea to have open connections floating about. Try to keep your connection local to the method where it is used so you can be sure it is closed and disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use transactions here. You can enclose all the code inside a single  transaction. when your application losses the connection to the database before committing, any still running transactions will be rolled back and terminated.
Please refer the following link to know more about Transactions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15